Not able to run the schedule job in pgagent
I have installed postgresql with pgagent and a scheduled a job. then I am trying to run the job manually, I am getting the error in event viewer

Failed to create new connection for connection string 'user=postgres dbname=postgres host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sampledb': connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

I am trying to schedule job for data retention policy
